# Can I get nested column in stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a `Select` into Stored Procedure:

```
SELECT
' ' AS MonthName
,gd.Month
,ISNULL(SUM(gd.Meta),0) AS Total
INTO #Meta
FROM [dbo].[Goal] g (NOLOCK)
 INNER JOIN [dbo].[GoalDetail] gd (NOLOCK)
    ON g.Id = gd.IdGoal
 INNER JOIN [dbo].[GoalClassification] gc (NOLOCK)
    ON gd.IdClassification = gc.Id
WHERE gc.Id IN (2,7)
      AND g.Year = YEAR(GETDATE())
      AND gd.Month = MONTH(GETDATE())
GROUP BY gd.Month
```

I want to get Foreign Key `BranchOfficeId`, but it is nested like:

Table `Goal` have `FKDepartment` and `Department` have fk of `BranchOfficeId`, how can I call this `BranchOfficeId` into my stored? Regards

----Update-----

```
SELECT
    ' ' AS MonthName
    ,gd.Month
    ,ISNULL(SUM(gd.Meta),0) AS Total
    INTO #Meta
    FROM [dbo].[Goal] g (NOLOCK)
     INNER JOIN [dbo].[GoalDetail] gd (NOLOCK)
        ON g.Id = gd.IdGoal
     INNER JOIN [dbo].[GoalClassification] gc (NOLOCK)
        ON gd.IdClassification = gc.Id
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Department] dep (NOLOCK) // there I call department but now how can I call branchOfficeId?
        ON g.IdDepartment = dep.Id
    WHERE gc.Id IN (2,7)
          AND g.Year = YEAR(GETDATE())
          AND gd.Month = MONTH(GETDATE())
    GROUP BY gd.Month
```

Comment: Can you add table definition of each table

Comment: Can you just add a 3rd join to the "Department" table?

Comment: So I can do:  `INNER JOIN [dbo].[Department] dep (NOLOCK)
  ON g.IdDepartment = dep.` ???? what supossed be there? my BranchOfficeIdfk? @David

Comment: The "ON" clause connects the same values from 2 different tables so `g.IdDepartment` needs to connect with the primary key on your department table.

Comment: You should probably take a peek at this article before you continue splattering NOLOCK hints all over the place. It is is far more sinister than most people realize. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Alright and now how can I get BranchOfficeId?  Note: the propouse of that is to get the value, of all BranchOfficeId, so in code I compare it with another value I have into user Table @David

Comment: This is probably pretty easy to answer once we know what your table structures are. Here is a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I update my question with your comments, can you check it and know me If I understand you @David

Comment: Nope. There is nothing like seeing the actual table definition...and this is nothing like seeing the actual table definition. Post up the ddl and this will answered in seconds with no guess work at all.